# How can i do Customization application in Android studio?

Tags: java, android

example i have 50 users in android. 
I want to do something different tasks for all users.
Example;
AA notification to user 1
BB notification to user 2
another notification to other user
How can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd need to be able to tell them appart you could iE. code a little snippet in there where on first start the app will connect to your server and get an ID.
Then you can either hardcode your actions for each ID or better you let the app connect to you server again and have it send it's ID. Then the server sends the tasks voila
another option would be to get their phone number and issue tasks based on their number. It's really hard to answer your question efficiently if you don't provide us with your limitations though